# C Client/Server Communication with HTML Page

Tags: html, c, browser, client

```
newsockfd = accept(sockfd, struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
FILE *write = fdopen(newsockfd, "w");
fprintf(write, "some html code is here");
fflush(write);

n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
printf(buffer);
```

The basic setup is a server written in C that waits for a client to connect then sends them html code to display the page.

When I don't have the last two lines of code this server works fine and I can connect to it with my browser and see the things I wrote in html displayed perfectly fine. The problem is on the page I have an html form so I want to be able to get what people type into the form on my C server. When I add the last two lines of code to read from the client and then try to connect to the server via my web browser I no longer see the form or anything else displayed on the web page and my server just waits for a response.

My question is why when I add those lines of code does the client no longer see what should be on the web page and is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to write a Web Server from scratch in C... I can't imagine a more difficult way of accomplishing this. The HTTP protocol is stateless. The Server listens on a TCP port for a new connection. A client connects and sends an HTTP request to the Server. The Server parses the HTTP request and sends an HTTP response back to the Client. The Client *disconnects*. Web browsers don't normally keep TCP connections open to a web server after receiving a response. There are exceptions to this, but that requires that you send special HTTP headers to the client and that your server supports it.

May I humbly suggest that you save yourself a lot of pain by doing the following:

- Install a webserver (apache would be sufficient). This will free you from all of the C socket code, letting you focus on the data handling instead.
- If you want to use C to process the interactions between the server and the client then you can use a CGI C library that does a lot of the HTTP drudgery for you. Something like http://www.boutell.com/cgic/ for example. Otherwise, Perl or PHP is a good option.

Comment: Can you help me with which HTTP headers I need to allow this? I really need to implement this in C without libraries.